# SQL syntax error at or near "ORDER" using PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

Here is my code:

```
SELECT
    customerid, numseats, fistname, surname, totalcost
FROM
    leadcutomer, flightbooking;
ORDER BY
    'totalcost' DESC;
```

The error I get is:

> ERROR: syntax error at or near "ORDER"

I am using [pgAdmin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PostgreSQL#Database_administration) 4. What is wrong with it?

Comment: Superfluous `;` at end of 2nd line methinks.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: `ORDER BY 'totalcost'` ... this is telling Postgres to order by a string, which doesn't make much sense.  Use `ORDER BY totalcost` instead.

Comment: "ERROR:  column reference "customerid" is ambiguous
LINE 1: SELECT customerid, numseats, firstname, surname, totalcost
               ^

Comment: This is what i am getting now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have more than one issue with the query.  I would write this as:

```
SELECT customerid, numseats, firstname, surname, totalcost
FROM leadcutomer l JOIN
     flightbooking b
     ON ?? = ??
ORDER BY totalcost DESC;
```

Specific issues:

- You are doing a `CROSS JOIN` and that is probably not intended.
- You are using a comma in the `FROM` clause instead of proper, explicit `JOIN` syntax.
- You have a semicolon at the end of the `FROM` clause.
- You are ordering by a constant, rather than a column.

Comment: SELECT customerid, numseats, firstname, surname, totalcost
FROM leadcustomer l JOIN
     flightbooking b
     ON customer.customerid = customerid
ORDER BY totalcost DESC;

Comment: I am missing a FROM clause entry for table customer, what am i doing wrong?

Comment: @PeterHorvath . . . `customer` <> `leadcustomer`.